# TinyMCE add Image not working

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, tinymce

I have the problem using TinyMCE and adding an image in there.
Using the Inline Editor for editing a text, the "adding of images" is working just fine. But using the normal editor (not inline) is working with adding an image.

But I think the real problem here is, that the "normal editor" is being used in a Bootstrap Popup, while the inline editor is used on the mainpage.

The problem I am experiencing is, not being able to enter the image url, when the "add image"-dialog is being opened. I cannot enter anything in "Source" (see below image).

[image]

Comment: Are you using IE? I have seen similar issues with text box not getting focus in IE when using bootstrap modals in conjunction with tinymce.

Comment: No, that's Chrome and Firefox I am using.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: No, not that I recall (its been two years) ^^
It needed a redesign of the application.